# SQL want to log values before and after update table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle9i

I have a problem here.

DB: oracle 9i

I want to save data changes after I execute `UPDATE` script on my table,
in that log I want to compare old values with new values.

How can i do this.

thanks for helping me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

write simple trigger, by using :OLD and :NEW you can get the value of both new and old value of the table

```
 create or replace
 trigger tg_name
  after UPDATE ON table_name
 for each row
 BEGIN
 IF :NEW.column1 = :OLD.column1 THEN
 -- any statement 
 END IF;    
-- you can log the old and new value by inserting into log table's too..
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a trigger on after update and you can use :old and :new values for each field you want.

Answer (score 0):

In case, if you need only updated values you can use RETURNING clause.

like

`UPDATE <table> SET (c1) = (v1), (c2) = (v2), (cn) = (vn) 
WHERE <condition> 
RETURNING <expression> INTO <variables>`

http://psoug.org/definition/RETURNING.htm